# Create custom column with type File in a custom list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, custom-list

My problem is I want to create a field of type "File" in a custom list. But my lists content type is "Item" which doesn't support such type of fields. The point of this manipulation is to update a field in my custom list from a field of type "File" in a document library using SharePoint Designer

Comment: What do you mean by field of type "File"?

Comment: Do you mean a column that will contain files like ATTACHMENTS does ? or something else

Comment: a column of type "File". you see in my document library there's a column that has a type "File" containing a word document. I want to update my custom list by adding the content of this column to a field in my list

Answer (score -1):

There is no "File" Content Type. You can watch the available Content Types under Site Settings ->  Site Content Types. If you want something different you have to create your own Content Type.

Comment: I am not talking about "File" content Type. a "File" column type exists. I have a column in my document library which stores word documents. this column is of type "File". what i want to do is to update a column in my custom list by adding the content (word) from the document library. A workflow in SPD will associate the word document in the document library with the new item created in the list

Comment: There isn't an OOTB column type "File", right? Do you have a content type which supports this field? You can add multiple content types to a list.

Comment: Yes i have a content type that supports this field but it inherits from the content type "document" and when i try to add it to my list it doesn't appear as an available content type. How can i add it ?

Comment: It's not possible, I did a little research.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms452896(v=office.14).aspx "any content type that you assign to a list must not derive from Document".

Comment: So, back to the basic question, how can i add a  word document from a document library to a list field ?

Comment: how about using a lookup field and then referring to the item from the document library?

Comment: the column containing the document in the document library is not referenced in the list of columns when i try to bind the document library to my list with the "Get information from" !

Comment: if you try to make a lookup field, the library is there but the field not? I set this up in my environment and it worked. Did you create the "File" field in Visual Studio or with the UI?

Comment: yes when i try to make the lookup field the library exists but the field is not there. The field having the type "File" is the result of an automatic generation of word documents: here is an explanation of the procedure >> http://www.quercussolutions.com/blog/index.php/out-of-the-box-document-generation-in-sharepoint-2/

Comment: this procedure generates a new document into a document library when you make a new entry into a custom list. I thought you want to do the opposite?

Comment: No,this procedure works fine but i want to complete it and  add the document ,generated in the document library, to the list. that's it

Comment: But that's exactly what you can't do. You cannot add a content type inheriting from document to a sharepoint list.

Comment: So, far from content types. Is there another way ? a workaround ?

Comment: Try it with a lookup column in your list. List -> Create Column -> Type: Lookup -> Get Information From: Your Doc Library -> In this Column: File